# Xdotool --window function not registering

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xdotools

I've bashed my head against this problem for a while and I'm at a dead end.

I'm simply trying to send one key input to an unfocused window using the `xdotool key --window window_id` function. The window is found, but nothing registers.

To simplify: I open two terminal windows. I run `xdotool getactivewindow` in terminal window A and get the window_ID. I run `xdotool key --window "window_ID_A" x` in terminal window B, the code runs, but nothing happens.

I've run some sanity checks like `sleep 5; xdotool key x` and then manually changing focus to terminal window A, which works as intended. I've tried running  `sleep 5; xdotool key --window "window_ID_A" x` and changing focus manually, but with no result.
When I enter a bogus window_ID: `xdotool key --window "window_ID_C" x` xdotool correctly reverts to using the focused window as the target, which leads me to believe that the correct window is being found in the original code. I've tried running --clearmodifiers, using notepad or libreoffice as my target window and even running with sudo, with no change. Nothing I try will make the --window function work.

Is there anything that might specifically hinder this functionality?

I'm running linux mint 20, Xfce 64-bit, x11

I usually figure these sorts of things out on my own eventually, but this is driving me nuts. Any help is hugely appreciated!

Edit:
The only workaround I've manage to come up with is this: `tmp=$(xdotool getactivewindow); xdotool windowactivate --sync $(xdotool search --name "window_name") key x; xdotool windowactivate $tmp`
Which is not a great workaround since my screen will flick to the other window and back, every time I run the script.